# How do I have a Flash bitmap fill be the same scale even if I resize or stretch the object?

Tags: flash, actionscript, scaleform

I am making buttons for scaleform with Flash. I want to have the background of each button be a grid of squares kind of like graph paper. I have been using bitmap fills of a grid in order to achieve this however if I simply stretch the button in any direction, the grid stretches along with it. I don't want this to happen.

I have attached a picture illustrating what I am talking about.[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g82i.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a Matrix parameter in beginBitmapFill() to counter scale against the size of the bitmap. The stretching is due to the button's scaling values affecting the child shape. The inverse of this should be used to re-render the bitmap fill.